# Windows - how do I run a script once another program exits normally?

Tags: windows, automation, windows-scripting

Specifically, I'm looking to create a script that backs up save games once a game is closed.

It's kind of like an EventListener in Javascript - I'd like to listen to the event of the game exiting, and accordingly trigger the script.

I realise I could simply make a script that launches the game itself, but I'd like to make a more independent utility that can be used for any game.

I have no experience in this domain. I thought maybe I could write a python script for it but I'm not sure how to know when the program exits.